# What are the differences between auto and 100%?

Tags: css

What are the differences between these two styles :

```
.styleOne {
     height: auto;
}

.styleTwo {
     height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `height: auto` = height is determined according to the items that are in div.

                                                                                                             
 `height: 100%` = height is determined by the parent element

Comment: additional look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing to affect how auto and 100% behave.

Answer (score 2):

With "height: auto" the height of the element will depend on the content in it. A height of 100% will make te element as high as its parent.

Note that if the height of the element is 100% and its parent has a fixed height but the position of the parent is not relative, the element will be as high as the html element.